# Redirect UIViewController for Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin

I am creating a method to display a dialog, this is what I made so far:

```
public void ShowDialog(String title = "",String msg = "")
{
    this.alert.Title = title;
    this.alert.AddButton("Ok");
    this.alert.Message = msg;
    this.alert.Show();
}
```

this is located to a common class so it can be used with other classes,

I want to add a parameter so that after pressing the "Ok" button it will redirect to a certain UIViewController, I tried it like this:

```
public void ShowDialog(String title = "",String msg = "", UIViewController view = null)
{
    this.alert.Title = title;
    this.alert.AddButton("Ok");
    this.alert.Message = msg;
    this.alert.Clicked += (object sender1, UIButtonEventArgs e) => {
                            if(e.ButtonIndex.ToString () == "0" && view != null){
                                NavigationController.PushViewController(view, true);
                            }
                        };
    this.alert.Show();
}
```

but clearly this is not working, am I missing something? or is this possible to do?

Thanks in advance..

**HOW I CALL IT**

```
Common common = new Common();
common.ShowDialog("Error","Invalid Process!!", new HomeScreen());
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "not working"?

Comment: it pops an error NullException on this line: NavigationController.PushViewController(view, true); and take note this method is residing on an independent class, not under uiviewcontroller

Comment: Can you give me a code line on how you call that method?

Comment: posted above on how I call it under a UIViewController

Comment: are you sure, ViewController where you call ShowDialog is inside UINavigationController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
public void ShowDialog(String title = "",String msg = "", UIViewController instance = null, UIViewController redirectTo = null)
{
    this.alert.Title = title;
    this.alert.AddButton("Ok");
    this.alert.Message = msg;
    this.alert.Clicked += (object sender1, UIButtonEventArgs e) => {
        if(e.ButtonIndex.ToString () == "0" && instance != null && redirectTo != null){
            instance.NavigationController.PushViewController(redirectTo, true);
        }
    };
    this.alert.Show();
}
```

then Call it like this:

```
Common common = new Common();
common.ShowDialog("Error","Invalid Process!", this, new HomeScreen());
```